How to properly redirect a domain to an apex application installed on an OCI server
I have an OCI server with apex & ords installed which I am able to access through a loadbalancer's public address 0.0.0.0/ords, which gives me access to the apex builder.
Here I can also access my apex application through 0.0.0.0/ords/r/workspace/app/login. I also have a domain name example.com.
How or where do I make my domain example.com send me to example.com/ords/r/workspace/app/login?

I have looked at the OCI loadbalancer, domain provider redirect\forwarding. I know its possible to achieve, I am just unable to find the right approach
